# Resetar um QAbstractListModel

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Gostaria de saber como faço para resetar ou limpar os dados de um QAbstractListModel? Eu estou utilizando a versao 5.6 da Qt.

O problema que estou tendo é quando eu tento realizar uma atualização das informações que estão no Model, onde eu preciso limpar os dados e reinseri-los, só que alguns dados pode não serem inseridos novamente, por isso precisaria realizar a limpezas dos dados. Porém quando eu uso o que eu montei ele funciona pela 1º vez ele limpa os dados e reinsere normalmente. A 2º ele limpa tbm porém quando fecho o programa ele da erro de **SIGSEGV** e da erro na unit de **atomic_base.h**

Porém oq eu consegui perceber é que quando eu comento esse trecho **this->foos->clear();**, no metodo *clear* da classe *FooModel*, não dá mais o erro mas a lista tbm não é resetada.

```
class FooModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum FooRoles {
        TypeRole = Qt::UserRole + 1, NameRole, PotionRole
    };
    FooModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~FooModel();
    void addFoo(const Foo &value);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    void clear();
protected:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
private:
    QList<Foo> *foos;
};

FooModel::FooModel(QObject *parent):QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
    this->foos = new QList<Foo>();
}

FooModel::~FooModel()
{
  delete(this->foos);
}

void FooModel::addFoo(const Food &value)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    foos->append(value);
    endInsertRows();
}

int FooModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return foos->count();
}

QVariant FooModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= foos->count())
        return QVariant();

    const Foo &foo = foos->at(index.row());
    switch (role) {
    case TypeRole:
        return "None";
        break;
    case NameRole:
        return foo.getName();
        break;
    case PotionRole:
        return "None";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return QVariant();
}

void FooModel::clear()
{
    beginResetModel();
    this->foos->clear();
    this->roleNames().clear();
    endResetModel();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> FooModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[TypeRole] = "type";
    roles[NameRole] = "name";
    roles[PotionRole] = "potion";
    return roles;
}
```

Comment: Se preferir, cole o código por cima desse, marque com o mouse e aperte o control+k que o sistema já formata o bloco. Ou, se preferir, tem o botão `{ }` na barrinha de edição que faz o mesmo.

Comment: Ficou beleza agora. Tou apagando meus comentários daqui pra nao deixar bagunça na sua pergunta. Qq duvida deixe comment que sempre tem alguem pra ajudar. E tem o chat também: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha

Comment: ele não aparece essa opção no code insight e também ta da erro ao compilar, eu olhei já em vários fóruns e eles me passam esse método, porém não consegui achar.

Comment: Veja se está aplicando no objeto certo. O reset é no model mesmo. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#reset (peguei rapidinho a documentação é da 4.8, mas acho que isso nao mudou na 5)

Comment: eu dei uma olhanda no QAbstractItemModel e só me mostra as seguintes metodos http://prntscr.com/bh50en e e no QAbstractListModel http://prntscr.com/bh50od

Comment: No qt 5 esse método foi descontinuado http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel-obsolete.html

Comment: É, realmente mudou. Só pra deixar a pergunta mais completinha, seria legal você acrescentar no seu texto uma descrição do erro que está dando, ou uma explicação do que acontece com seu código atual. Talvez ajude alguém a achar o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom consegui achar a solução. O problema era que o os objetos não estavam sendo destruídos.

### O método clear

```
void FooModel::clear()
{
    beginResetModel();

    this->foos->clear();

    qDeleteAll(*foos);

    endResetModel();
}
```

### Exemplo completo

**Header**

```
class FooModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum FooRoles {
        TypeRole = Qt::UserRole + 1, NameRole, PotionRole
    };
    FooModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~FooModel();
    void addFoo(Foo *value);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    void clear();
protected:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
private:
    QList<Foo*> *foos;
};
```

**Cpp**

```
FooModel::FooModel(QObject *parent):QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
    this->foos = new QList<Foo*>();
}

FooModel::~FooModel()
{
    delete(this->foos);
}

void FooModel::addFoo(Foo *value)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    foos->append(value);
    endInsertRows();
}

int FooModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return foos->count();
}

QVariant FooModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= foos->count())
        return QVariant();

    const Foo *foo = foos->at(index.row());
    switch (role) {
    case TypeRole:
        return "None";
        break;
    case NameRole:
        return foo->getName();
        break;
    case PotionRole:
        return "None";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return QVariant();
}

void FooModel::clear()
{
    beginResetModel();

    this->foos->clear();

    qDeleteAll(*foos);

    endResetModel();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> FooModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[TypeRole] = "type";
    roles[NameRole] = "name";
    roles[PotionRole] = "potion";
    return roles;
}
```